# extract string by first or second space from column depending on adjacent columns value Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame that contains product codes and product types.

```
material_description            component_type_or_status
SF 1243545gbe ff ee rr oo       SF
LF 2324344ire ff ee rr oo       LF
BF 3434333fre ff gg hh 23       BF
IA SF 3434333fre ff gg 22 re    IA
ZZ LF 34391r33b ff tn 33        ZZ
```

I would like to create a new column called material code which extracts the second string or third string from the left side of product code column depending on the value of product type

If **SF**, **BF** or **LF** return string after first white space from left

If **IA** or **ZZ** return string after second white space from left

Here's my function. It's stuck in a loop and I'm not sure if my logic is correct.
What's the best way to do this with Pandas?

```
def parse_material_description(x):
    df = infile.parse(sheet_name='Unit of Measure')
    df['component_type_or_status'] = df['Material Description'].str[:2]

    try:
        if x['component_type_or_status'] == 'SF':
            df['material_code'] = df['Material Description'].str.split(" ",1)

        elif x['component_type_or_status'] == 'LF':
            df['material_code'] = df['Material Description'].str.split(" ",1)

        elif x['component_type_or_status'] == 'BF':
            df['material_code'] = df['Material Description'].str.split(" ",1)

        elif x['component_type_or_status'] == 'IA':
            df['material_code'] = df['Material Description'].str.split(" ",2)            

        elif x['component_type_or_status'] == 'ZZ':
            df['material_code'] = df['Material Description'].str.split(" ",2)            

        elif x['component_type_or_status'] == None:
            return ''
    except: IndexError

df['component_type_or_status'] = df.apply(parse_material_description, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be a bit easier using `np.where` in a single line:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'material':['SF 1243545gbe ff ee rr oo','LF 2324344ire ff ee rr oo','ZZ LF 34391r33b ff tn 33'],'type':['SF','LF','ZZ']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['material_code'] = np.where(df['type'].isin(['SF','LF','BF']),df['material'].str.split(" ").str.get(1),df['material'].str.split(" ").str.get(2))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                    material type material_code
0  SF 1243545gbe ff ee rr oo   SF    1243545gbe
1  LF 2324344ire ff ee rr oo   LF    2324344ire
2   ZZ LF 34391r33b ff tn 33   ZZ     34391r33b
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it:

**Code:**

```py
df['material code']=''
for i in range(0,len(df['component_type_or_status'])):
    if (df['component_type_or_status'][i] == 'SF') or (df['component_type_or_status'][i] == 'LF') or (df['component_type_or_status'][i] == 'BF'):
        df['material code'][i]=' '.join(df['material_description'][i].split()[1:2])
    else:
        df['material code'][i]=' '.join(df['material_description'][i].split()[2:3])
```

**Output:**

```py
    material_description            component_type_or_status    material code
0   SF 1243545gbe ff ee rr oo       SF                          1243545gbe
1   LF 2324344ire ff ee rr oo       LF                          2324344ire
2   BF 3434333fre ff gg hh 23       BF                          3434333fre
3   IA SF 3434333fre ff gg 22 re    IA                          3434333fre
4   ZZ LF 34391r33b ff tn 33        ZZ                          34391r33b
```

`df` here being your initial dataframe.

Comment: There's no need to use for and if, you can use other functions that are a lot more efficient. Also, I think op wishes to get only the 1/2 position in the list not starting from that position onwards.

Comment: @CeliusStingher You are right, `np.where` should have been the obvious choice. Why did I not think about that ? :)

Answer (score 0):

If your material_codes are representative, you could do this instead;

```py
df['material_code'] = df['material_description'].str.extract(r'\s+([a-z0-9]+)\s+')
```